# Dealing with events not included in older versions of MS Office

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a code that can be used both in newer and older versions on Word for macOS.
Some old versions of Word don't support the Document_BuildingBlockInsert event, which causes a compile-time error whenever another event such as Document_Open occurs.

I've tried conditional compiling, checking for vba7 compatibility, but apparently there are versions of MS Word for macOS that are compatible with vba7 and don't include the BuildingBlockInsert event. How can I deal with this?

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  'this code should run on all versions of word
End sub


#If VBA7 Then
  Private Sub Document_BuildingBlockInsert(...) 'this line causes a compile-time error
    'this code should run on newer versions of word
  End Sub
#End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  'this code should run on all versions of word
End sub

#If VBA7 Then
  Private Sub Document_BuildingBlockInsert(...)
    On Error Resume Next 
    '...
    If Err.Number = XXX Then ' choose a number
       Exit Sub
    End If
    'this code should run on newer versions of word
    '...
  End Sub
#End If
```

Or

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
  'this code should run on all versions of word
  Dim version As String
  version = Application.Version
  If version >= "16.0" Then 'check version that works, 16 is a guess
    'Enable the Document_BuildingBlockInsert event
  Else
    'Disable the Document_BuildingBlockInsert event
  End If
End sub
```